# MobgoDB Custom member serializer

Tags: c#, mongodb

The following example is just an example...
I have this User class which is a bson document. when writing to the database, I want that the member `UserInfo` will write the `Passport` value and as an object.

I need a custom mapper/serializer that will allow me to instruct mongo driver to take the `Passport`

```
public class User{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public UserInfo Info<User> {get;set;}
}

public class Info<T>{
   public string Passport{get;set;}
}
```

Bottom line I need this:

```
{Name : "my user name", UserInfo : "41554545"}
```

and not this:

```
{Name : "my user name", UserInfo : {"Passport" :"41554545"}
```

Thanks

Comment: So why should it do that? You actually defined your class to use the other class as it's member property. If you want the value serialized in storage as a plain string then don't map it into another class in the first place.

Comment: My case is different and much more complex, I have simplified it for the community to understand.

Comment: I think it's more misguided than complex, at least in the form presented here. If you start structuring classes in a "wildly" different way from the actual data storage then it's a slippery slope down into complete miscomprehension. Part of the beauty of working with a "document oriented database" is that the "stored/serialized" data can actually have a direct correlation to the class structure within the application domain. The moment you change that you're just adding unnecessary complexity. You "juggle" things with a traditional "flat" table type store, not a document/object database.

Comment: I did not as for help in architecture, I asked help in a specific technical matter. this was the best way to describe my question.